# How to get time from jquery Timepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use jQuery timepicker that was extended to be able to pick not only the date but also the time. [Adding a Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker.](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) This is how I pick the data:

```
$('#test').live('click', function(){
        $('body').append('<div id="timePicker"></div>');
        var d = new Date();
        $('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date()
        });
});
```

From the examples the date is pasted into the input field. But I do not want to have an input field, I just have a button `#test`. The done button of the picker does only work for input fields. How can I fix that and how to I get the date without an input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the input field using CSS

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="dateTimeField" />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: hm good idea, but #timePicker is in the demo's both input field and container where the timePicker is appended